# nmap -sn lists all active hosts on my network, but nmap -sL does not

Tags: nmap

When I execute `nmap -sn 192.168.1.1-255`, I get:

```
Nmap scan report for router (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.037s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.17   # This is my smart TV
Host is up (0.054s latency).
Nmap scan report for prometheus (192.168.1.164)
Host is up (0.0020s latency).
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 9.71 seconds
```

This output is an accurate account of all of the online hosts on my home network at the time. However, when I run `nmap -sL 192.168.1.1-255` immediately after, I get:

```
Nmap scan report for router (192.168.1.1)
…
Nmap scan report for android-cae4e91f5179dac4 (192.168.1.81)
…
Nmap scan report for Owner-PC (192.168.1.118)
Nmap scan report for prometheus (192.168.1.164)
…
Nmap scan report for kindle-707ed367c (192.168.1.187)
…
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 8.33 seconds
```

The `android`, `Owner-PC`, and `Kindle` have all connected to my network previously (though at the time I ran `nmap -sL`, they were not up). Meanwhile, the smart TV (`192.168.1.17`), *isn't* listed. Reading the man-page on these options doesn't shed any light for me on why this should be the case. Can anybody provide me with a more intuitive explanation of the difference between these two options?

Comment: Tip: You can say `192.168.1.*` here and get the same effect. Technically it differs, in that it also scans `192.168.1.0`, but that's harmless. Another shorter syntax that works is `192.168.1.0/24`. That can be helpful when you're dealing with CIDR masks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I read the "help" output of `nmap`, "-sL" lists out the possible scan targets. On my little intranet, `nmap` clearly does DNS lookups: in addition to IP addresses, it gives the DNS names I've assigned, even if those hosts aren't even plugged in. But in any case, `nmap -sL` just lists IP addresses and host names, it doesn't actually send a packet to see what happens. `nmap -sn` does a ping-scan of the specified subnet.  `nmap` sends ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to IP addresses, and shows you what answered.

In your listing above, you've elided all the plain IP addresses, those without a DNS name. My guess is that the IP address 192.168.1.117 is one of the plain IP addresses - your "smart TV" didn't do DHCP with a nickname that got into the DNS/DHCP server's tables. Since all that `nmap -sL` does is list IP addresses, and possibly hostnames it gets from DNS, the "smart TV" "doesn't show up" as aything momre than an IP address.

So that's the behavior one would want from `nmap`.  Executed with "-sn" it shows you what IP addresses answer ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets. Executed with "-sL" it just lists IP addresses. Try "-sL" with different subnets, like "192.168.1.0/24" and "192.168.1.0/28" to see the difference. Go crazy and do `nmap -sL 10.0.0.0/24` to see what that says. Since your DHCP is giving out 192.168.1.x addresses, and 10.x.y.z addresses aren't routable, you should be convinced that you're just seeing a listing.

Comment: Running `nmap -sL --traceroute` provides additional host information for `192.168.1.17` indicating to me that the TV is indeed up, but lacks a name in the DNS/DHCP server table

Comment: Great answer. Your note about ICMP Echo Request packets is not quite right, though. [Nmap uses lots of techniques to discover hosts](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html), but ICMP Echo Request is *hardly ever* used on a local LAN. Instead Nmap uses simple ARP requests, which are a prerequisite to any IP communication on Ethernet-like links.